# Weird white fuzz around textures with transparent areas in Viewport (2.91)

Tags: texturing, node-editor, 3d-view, transparency

More of a visual frustration since this doesn't affect the actual Cycles renders, but since I upgraded from 2.9 to 2.91, materials with a Transparent BDSF + Mix Shader have a weird white fuzz even when set to Alpha Hashed. This oddity doesn't appear anywhere in 2.9, as these files were from that version directly. Any fixes? Or do I have to put up with it?

[image: What it looks like in Viewport with Node setup]

Node setup:
[image]

Comment: You mean the troubles you have are when using EEVEE? Try using alpha-clip and manually setting the clip threshold.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Sorry, this is the plain Cycles setup, I haven't used EEVEE at all.

What you're seeing here is the Material view, not Render.

Comment: The material preview is rendered using the Eevee engine, but it uses (almost) the same nodes as cycles. Please show the whole node tree so we can try to pinpoint the culprit. In the meantime try unplugging the normal and setting emission strength to 0 if there is any

Comment: @Gorgious
Here's my setup. Normal has been unplugged.